# How do I manage an Android/Eclipse/Git project across multiple platforms?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, gitignore

I'm working on an Android group project, and have been running into issues with Eclipse's .metadata folder and git.

Originally, I didn't include the .metadata folder, which caused one teammate's eclipse workspace to completely break. The projects wouldn't show up in the package explorer, and the SDK couldn't be found. I am working under OSX and they're on Windows. So then I included the .metadata folder, and that fixed the problem with the projects not being found, but the commits are a nightmare! There are always thousands of insertions/deletions and the SDK is found, but it points to the wrong place.

Another issue is `bin/` and `gen/` files still show up as added/modified in Git. I know I'm missing something that is probably very obvious.

**My .gitignore**

```
# Trying to get bin/gen to not show up in Windows
AllTests/bin
AllTests/gen
Fire-Alert/bin
Fire-Alert/gen

# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/
target/
/bin
/gen

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Mac .DS_Store files
.DS_Store
```

**File structure of my Eclipse workspace:**

```
├── .git
│   ├── branches
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── info
│   ├── logs
│   ├── objects
│   └── refs
├── .metadata
│   └── .plugins
├── AllTests
│   ├── .settings
│   ├── assets
│   ├── bin
│   ├── gen
│   ├── res
│   └── src
└── Fire-Alert
    ├── .metadata
    ├── .settings
    ├── assets
    ├── bin
    ├── gen
    ├── libs
    ├── res
    └── src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `.metadata` in my Android projects managed with Git and Eclipse. I don't think you need it.

As per `bin/` and `gen/` files showing up as added/modified in Git... It would seem they were inadvertently added to version control. You can remove them with:

```
git rm --cached bin/ gen/
git commit -m 'cleaning up bin/ and gen/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved my problem using your answer and another step. I didn't realize that **if a file is already tracked, then it will not be affected by adding it to .gitignore**. After this clicked with me, I simply removed bin/ gen/ and .metadata as you instructed and made sure they were all in my .gitignore. Then I instructed my teammates to do the same. Since the metadata held the project information, new team members had to import the project into their workspace and set up their run environments. Now the repo is clean as a whistle.